# Can I trust these programs? Are they safe? What are they really?

Tags: windows, spyware

I found a couple programs on the desktop of my computer after another person used it.  I have done some googling, but have no idea who or what I can and cannot trust.  The programs in question are called:

- DriverCure Installer.exe
- DriverDetective.exe

What are these programs?  Can I trust them?  Why would a person download them?

Comment: http://wakoopa.com/executables/driverdetective-exe

Comment: You might want to re-evaluate your computer's security to avoid these uninvited programs appearing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I trust them?

No! ParetoLogic is on record for **computer fraud**, i wouldn't touch their products (DriverCure, Driver Detective, DriverGuide, DriverUpdates, DriverPro) with a barge pole, certainly mailcious software in my books!

The interwebs are full with complaints about the company.

**[www.complaintsboard.com](http://www.complaintsboard.com/complaints/regcureparetologic-inc-c280835.html)**

**[www.ripoffreport.com](http://66.102.9.132/search?q=cache:whw6c62P03kJ:www.ripoffreport.com/Computer-Fraud/ParetoLogic-com-Driv/paretologic-com-drivercure-d-5488f.htm+paretologic+driverdetective&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ie&client=firefox-a)**

**[suckered.org](http://suckered.org/st-xoftspyse.html)**

> Why would a person download them?

If you looking for **decent** software to backup your drivers and keep them updated, get **[DriverMax](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/DriverMax.shtml)**:

> DriverMax is a new tool that allows
>   you to download the latest driver
>   updates for your computer. No more
>   searching for rare drivers on discs or
>   on the web or inserting one
>   installation CD after the other. Just
>   create a free account, log in, and
>   start downloading the updates that you
>   need.
>
> You can also export all your current
>   drivers (or just the ones that work
>   ok) to a folder or a compressed file.
>   After reinstalling Windows you will
>   have everything in one place!

Comment: Is this company related to driverguide.com ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't trust any software that just "appears" unless you have a known good [md5 or sha1 hash checker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) you can use to verify it's contents.  Anyone can name anything 'driver detective'.

Answer (score 2):

DriverCure is a malware as i can see. DriverCure.com website is a FAKE website and DriverCure is also a fake program. I suggest you to just dont take a chance with these programs.

Comment: The interface does look like one of the many fake antivirus-viruses, it is a genuine program.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these programs are genuine non malware - providing they are in the correct location and downloaded from the correct sites.

[Driver Cure](http://www.drivercure.com/) updates device drivers and many programs whilst [Driver detective](http://www.drivershq.com/) is just for drivers.

There is nothing wrong and these programs do work, however, I personally do not like these sort of programs and update drivers manually from the manufacturers website.

Comment: -1 there is a LOT wrong with these programs, do some research before endorsing computer fraudsters!

Comment: How am I endorsing them? I can't stand these programs, but I installed inside a virtual machine to see and they do work.

Comment: you're calling "Both of these programs ... genuine non malware" when in fact they're quite the opposite.

Comment: @Molly this doesn't mean that I am endorsing them - just because a program is rubbish doesn't mean it is malware.

Comment: Wil, 'nothing wrong', 'genuine' and 'non malware' is just NOT true.

Comment: Wil, I hear where you are coming from - I doubt these people are willfully creating malware.  But I think Molly was trying to say given your rep on this site, not pointing out ParetoLogics' reptutation problems (http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/drivercure.com) is an implcit endorsement.  Their history is checkered, having left a long list of angry customers in their wake.  Malware? No.  Can I *trust* them? No.

Comment: @DaveParillo Fully agree - little busy right now but will rephrase, I didn't think there would be confusion and under no circumstance would I recommend these applications. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know it, ditch it. The Anti-Virus web sites are a good source of information for this kind of thing. There are also sites like ScamBusters and HoaxKill that are good for that.